# what is the correct way and place to define setup/teardown fixture in pytest that will execute function from module?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have all key parameters set up in conftest.py at root of my tests directory.
I also have a module.py module with functions that are called from my tests. module.py require parameters defined in conftest.py. Right now what I have in these files is:

*tests/module/module.py:*

```
import conftest

def delete_team_master(team_id):
   'delete team code'
```

*tests/conftest.py:*

```
import pytest
from module.module import delete_team_master


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def setup():
    print('Setting up an environment')
    yield
    print('Executing teardown procedure')
    delete_team_master(test_team_master)
```

This configuration works and my teardown function gets executed without issues.

I wanted somehow to move this teardown code to the module in order to get rid of cross imports between module and conftest, but when this fixture is moved to module.py it's not executed at the end of the session.

What would be the good way to do it? any ideas?

Comment: Don't import from `conftest`s, it's a source for future errors. Move the code to be reused from `conftest` to `module` and import `module` in `conftest`. As for fixtures, they are only discovered in test modules, `conftest`s or from plugin modules.

Comment: @hoefling - I have all config and environment related parameters defined in conftest. my module contains methods that rely on those (ie: credentials, environment urls...).  Perhaps, to move this stuff out to for example `config.py` that will be imported by `module` and then `module` would be imported by `conftest` - what do you think.? How do you structure it?